# Xamarin: System.Nullreferenceexception when try to deserialize object

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I try to deserialize object and get System.NullReferenceException. I can't find where exception is fired and what is the cause of exception.

I try to deserialize like this:

```
public static List<T> Get<T>()
{
    string path = GetFilePath (typeof(T));
    List<T> list;
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader (path)) 
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(List<T>));                     
        list = (List<T>)serializer.Deserialize (stream);                        
    }
    return list;
}
```

StackTrace

> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.OnUnknownNode
>   (System.Xml.XmlNode node, System.Object o, System.String qnames)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.UnknownNode
>   (System.Object o, System.String qnames) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.UnknownNode
>   (System.Object o) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadListElement
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, Boolean isNullable,
>   System.Object list, Boolean canCreateInstance) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadObject
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, Boolean isNullable,
>   Boolean checkType) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadRoot
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping rootMap) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadRoot ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader reader) [0x00000] in
>   :0

Comment: What does `GetFilePath` return? What's in the file?

Comment: GetFilePath returns path of the file. In file is Xml document. Content is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfBusinessOffer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <BusinessOffer>

  </BusinessOffer>
</ArrayOfBusinessOffer>

Comment: And are you sure that `GetFilePath` itself is doing the right thing? Have you debugged through to check that?

Comment: Yes, I have debugged GetFilePath. I can get the content of xml file like this string text = File.ReadAllText (path). The correct content of xml file without semicolons is                                                     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfBusinessOffer xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<BusinessOffer> 
</BusinessOffer>
</ArrayOfBusinessOffer>

Comment: But I continue get System.NullReferenceException

Answer (score 1):

The XML you've pasted is invalid.  I tried pasting it into Notepad, saving as test.xml and opening in Chrome.  It looks like it doesn't like the semicolons.  I took them out to leave me with the following which opened fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfBusinessOffer xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<BusinessOffer>
</BusinessOffer>
</ArrayOfBusinessOffer>
```

Comment: I continue get System.NullReferenceException. What can be the cause?